# generate agitar test cases with Gradle

Tags: gradle

I am currently generating agitar test cases through eclipse.

But, is there any way that we can generate ( not run ) agitar test cases with Gradle.

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with agitar but assuming it's just a jar in a maven repo

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'foo.bar:agitar:x.y.z'
    }
}

task generateAgitar {
    File inputDir = file("src/main/java")
    File outputDir = file("$buildDir/agitar")
    inputs.dir inputDir
    outputs.dir outputDir
    doLast {
        outputDir.mkdirs()
        foo.bar.agitar.SomeAgitarGenerator generator = new foo.bar.agitar.SomeAgitarGenerator();
        generator.generate(inputDir, outputDir)
    }
}
```